# Strange issue with network on Dell Inspiron N5110 running windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

I have been struggling with this for 3 days now and yet no answers have been revealed.

I have an Intel Centrino N-1030 network adapter in my laptop and everything was fine, until at a point it randomly started saying that I have "limited access" to any network that I connect to. So I can see networks and connect too them, yet there is no internet connection. I have tried on several routers and mobile hotspots and still no luck. I then realized I cannot activate my firewall, whenever I try it simply says; "Action center can't turn on windows firewall." I tried manually turning it on, but it still does not work. Apart from this, when I open Network and Sharing center my network map is missing completely, there is a grey icon and simply says unknown. Just below this it states that "the dependency service or group failed to start. My Intel WiFi technology says that there was no Intel network adapter found on the laptop, but I have uninstalled and reinstalled all necessary drivers and still nothing has helped.

I have limited knowledge to what is going on here and I would really appreciate any help that anyone could possibly offer.

I have also tried restarting the network and firewall services. I have flushed my DNS and released and renewed IPs.